# Coverage issues due to children component not being captured

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getLocale, getEnvironment } from '../utils/data';
import provide from '../scripts/provide';
import Provide from './Provide';
import Render from './Render';

const Widget = ({
  environment,
  locale,
  rOptions
}) => (rOptions ? (
  <Render
    rOptions={rOptions}
  />
) : (
  <Provide
    options={{
      environment,
      locale,
    }}
  >
    {(options) => (
      <Render
        rOptions={options}
      />
    )}
  </Provide>
));

Widget.provide = provide;

export const mapState = (state) => ({
  locale: getLocale(state),
  environment: getEnvironment(state),
});

export default connect(mapState)(Widget);
```

Trying to test it to get full coverage.

But I am currently not getting the coverage for the following:

```
{(options) => (
    <Render
      rOptions={options}
    />
  )}
```

This is cos I have mocked Provide as follows.

```
jest.mock('../../src/components/Provide', () => 'Provide');
```

How could I modify this mock for it to have children to be able to get coverage for it?

The test for this Provide with render as children bit.

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
it('should render', () => {
    const Widget = require('../../src/components/Widget').default;
    const renderedModule = mount(<Widget {...defaultProps} />);
    expect(renderedModule.find('Provide')).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

The snapshot looks like this:

```
exports[`Widget should render 1`] = `
<Provide
  options={
    Object {
      "environment": "mock environment",
      "locale": "mock locale",
    }
  }
>
  <Component />
</Provide>
`;
```

If mocked correctly, the `<Component />` should have been `<Render ... />`

Other mocks in the test not relevant I believe. Leaving it in for reference.

```
jest.mock('../../src/components/Render', () => () => 'Render');
jest.mock('../../src/scripts/provide', () => () => 'mock provide');

jest.mock('../../src/utils/data', () => ({
  getLocale: () => 'mock locale',
  getEnvironment: () => 'mock environment',
}));
```